# How to use poisson to estimate arrival time (generate random integers)?

Tags: python, poisson-distribution, random-generation

In my assignment, I'm supposed to use a distribution curve to describe how many minutes will the employee come to work in advanced or later than the planed start time.

I decided to use Poisson distribution to solve my case. However, I don't know how should I assign the parameter to the Poisson function. I want my x-axis is from 0 to 60 minute (integer). The peak of the curve should be show up when x is 15. Should I just assign the lambda as 15?

I don't know if it's correct to use Poisson distribution to estimate the arrival time, and also don't know, if Poisson is correct, then should I just let the lambda be 15 and that's it, how can I set up a specific range (0, 60)?

Comment: This random time integer is a very small part of my project. I need integer, because the data that I have is measured every 1 minute. I want to generate a random integer to shift my data. I checked a lot of distribuations, I found no one which fits my problem

Comment: The mode of the Poisson distribution is located at the rounded-down integer value of the parameter, so any number in the interval $[15, 16)$ will make the peak at 15.  15 will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) may be better suited to the problem you describe. A poisson distribution is basically a binomial distribution in the limit, and is a good approximation when the number of trials $n$ is large and the probability $p$ of the Bernoulli process is small. Thus $\lambda \approx np$, where $\lambda$ is the mean expected value. And, if you want the average value to be 15, you should use the distribution $Poi(\lambda = 15)$.

To calculate the probability k events, use the following formula:
$$P(K = k) = \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$$

Comment: Thank you. Poisson is not the choice for me. I decided to use truncated normal distribution.